# The right way to pushViewController When use UISearchController

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I use `UISearchController` to handle my search stuff, in my `SearchResultsController`, when I tap searched cell, the code `[self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES]` does not working, see:

[image]

The `self.navigationController` equals nil.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just embed your view controller in a `UINavigationController`? I believe you can hide the navigation bar if that bothers you.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. Post _code_. Thanks. And we need to see much more context; where is that code being called? I don't even know what `self` _is_ from what you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If self.navigationcontroller is nil probably the current viewcontroller is not launched/pushed in a navigationcontroller.

From your screenshot i believe that ProjectsSearchViewController is not pushed into a navigationController.

Have you tried to add your viewcontroller to UINavigationController. Say like this

```
ProjectsSearchViewController *searchVC = [ProjectsSearchViewController alloc] init]
// ProjectsSearchViewController object can be created by any means storyboard/IB/ Programmatically
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: searchVC];
```